# Can the substitute-and-expand model of Scheme macros be improved?

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

As far as I know, the pattern&template-based Scheme macro system works by first pattern matching a macro invocation, obtaining a substitution in case of success, applying the resulted substitution to the corresponding template to build up a (maybe) partially-expanded expression, and then continuously expanding the resulted expression.  If what I describe is true (please correct me otherwise), then it seems to me this building-up and expanding-again model is not efficient.  Why does the expansion need to be done like this?  Is it possible to finish the expansion by a run down the template once and for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that macros can be handled define time for procedures and compile time for a whole program.

Also, a macro expansion might turn into another (or similar) macro form that needs expanding. Eg. you can make a macro that ends up as a `cond` expression which of course is a macro for nested `if` expressions in most Schemes.

Have you seen [Alexpander](http://petrofsky.org/src/alexpander.scm)? It evaluates a program (in one expression) and returns an equal program without macros.

Comment: What is _define time_?  Also, I am not sure I get the reasoning in your second paragraph.  Could you describe the reason why in such a case the way I suggested (one run) could not handle?

Comment: Well imagine `(mymacro xxx yyy)` is replaced with `(cond ((eq? xxx 0) expr) ((eq? xxx 1) expr2) (else expr3))` it is not done processing since `cond` is  a macro.. The end result might be `(if (eq? xxx 0) (begin expr1) (if (eq? xxx 1) (begin expr2) (begin expr3))` but it also can be macro to the implementations underlying primitives. `begin` is in the result and it is a macro that needs expanding... etc.

Comment: Define time==I'm thining evaluation of procedures. Usually done before procedure invocation and at compile time for compiled code.

Comment: What I did not understand is that why I cannot immediately continuously expanding `cond` when I see it, rather than build up the expression and then expand it.  This model of macro expansion is analog to the inefficient substitution-based model for the $\lambda$-calculus.  There one wave of substitution is done, a new expression is built-up and reduction continues on this expression.  But there a delayed-substitution can be achieved via an environment.  So what I am asking is whether a similar trick can be done for macro expansion?

Comment: What do you mean by building up the expression? Surely you need a whole resulting form before you check if the resulting form itself is a macro and if not if any of it's resulting parts is a macro? You need the whole to check if the pattern matches as well (it might not). You might even be able to expand these before when the syntax gets compiled (like `mymacro` gets a tran formation directly to `if`) but that will only work for the lexical variables. The pattern symbols are like variables that can be syntax as well.

Comment: By "building up the expression" I mean, pattern variables in the template are replaced by their bindings so that the template is turned into an expression.  But when I see the template, I can already tell whether the build-up expression would be a macro use or not by just examining the head of the template.  So I can just continue the expansion, rather than first build an intermediate expression up and then expand it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45842/discussion-between-plmday-and-sylwester)

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of the macro system are specified in the way you describe.  However, implementations are free to implement that specification any way they want; in particular, they could "inline" macro expansions ahead of time to speed the process of macro expansion.

I'm not aware of any Scheme implementations that do what you describe, and I would guess it's because macro expansion is not usually a big bottleneck in compilation.

Comment: I have seen two implementations of `syntax-case`, one by R. Kent Dybvig (documented in two papers) and one by André van Tonder (see [expander.scm](http://www.het.brown.edu/people/andre/macros/december-27-07/expander.scm)) do what I described.

Comment: @plmday I don't think StackOverflow is intended for rhetorical questions. If you already know the answer ("yes it can be improved"), then you should post the answer -- and mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: @GregHendershott: I realized I misunderstood John.  By "what you describe" he was referring to my questioned way: a one run model.  Whereas when I said "what I described", I was referring to my described way, that is, the build-up and then expand model.  So, no, it is not a rhetorical question.

Comment: It looks to me like you're confusing semantics with implementation. Let me know if that doesn't make sense to you.